# High Training and Validation accuracy but cannot predict even a single image correctly

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, pre-trained-model

i have trained a model on GTSRB(german traffic sign dataset)it has approx 39K pictures of sizes vary from 16x16 to 128x128 for 43 classes.Training accuracy=97% , validation accuracy=91% . But when i predcit any image of my own , it never recognize correctly.Below is my code pictures

[Libraries and accessing data is shown.i have also tried other way without using imagedatagenerator but same problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOtlZ.png)

[here is my model. I also tried it with input shape(64,64) but same problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQa2D.png)

[here is how i am predicting my images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gr6Ur.png)

[here is my model.fit results with loss and acc. %](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDWdk.png)

Comment: Have you checked your images are "similar" to the ones in the training set? For instance does the traffic signs appear roughly the same size/area and is it centered?

Comment: Please include your code as text not images